# Match email addresses not separated by semicolons

Tags: regex, oracle, email, regex-negation

I need to match using oracle sql "REGEXP_LIKE" in some texts all the multiple emails that are separated by blanks and not semicolon.
I've used successfully the following regexp

```
\@.*(\ )+.*\@.*
```

That was enough for my needs, until a clever guy has started to introduce multiple emails in this format

```
 email@domain ; email@domain
```

And my previous regular expression fails. 
What I want is match

```
 email@domain  email@domain
```

(email separated by a number of blanks)
but discard the:

```
 email@domain ; email@domain
```

(email separated by blanks, but with a semicolon)

Is there a simple way to achieve this??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language are you using for your application code? Regex features available for use differ in some languages..

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, thank you for the question. I missed to specify this. I should have to use oracle regexp_like. I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

From the `.*` in your original expression, I see that you're not too fussed about specifying what chars in the email address are valid. So I'd suggest something like this:

```
^([^[:space:]@;]+@[^[:space:]@;]+(\s*))+$
```

**Sample Usage**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(mycolumn, '^([^[:space:]@;]+@[^[:space:]@;]+(\s*))+$', 'c');
```

**Regex Explanation**

```
^([^[:space:]@;]+@[^[:space:]@;]+(\s*))+$
```

- Assert position at the beginning of the string `^`
- Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 `([^[:space:]@;]+@[^[:space:]@;]+(\s*))+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
  - Match any single character that is NOT present in the list below and that is NOT a line break character (line feed) `[^[:space:]@;]+`

    - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
    - A character from the POSIX character class “space” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) `[:space:]`
    - A single character from the list “@;” `@;`
  - Match the character “@” literally `@`
  - Match any single character that is NOT present in the list below and that is NOT a line break character (line feed) `[^[:space:]@;]+`

    - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
    - A character from the POSIX character class “space” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) `[:space:]`
    - A single character from the list “@;” `@;`
  - Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 `(\s*)`

    - Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) `\s*`

      - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
- Assert position at the very end of the string `$`

Comment: Reading the answer only now... no email notifications, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can replace the ";" in the text with the amount of blanks and then use your already existing method for separating the e-mails. This can work if you do not use ";" anywhere else in the text. (You don't want to replace those ones!) What programming language do you use? Do you refer to string when using "some text"?